# Applying tensorflow model on larger inputs block by block

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

This is a somewhat simplified version of the problem:
I have a tf.keras Model that takes inputs of shape (5,3) and produces outputs of (5,1). I want to apply it to data that has shape (10,3) and get an output to be (10,1) by applying the model to consecutive blocks of 5 rows. Is there an effective way of doing it?

I tried wrapping the model in reshape layers, ex:

```
original_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input((5, 3), name='inputs'),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(8, kernel_size=1, padding='valid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])


l1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((10, 3), name='inputs2')
l2 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((2, 5, 3))(l1)
l3 = original_model(l2)
l4 = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((10, 1), input_shape=(2, 5, 1))(l3)

new_model = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=l1,
            outputs=l4)
```

but that introduces an extra dimensions and causes an error:

> ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "model_4"
> (type Functional).
> Input 0 of layer "sequential_9" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 5, 3), found shape=(None, 2, 5, 3)

Comment: that entirely depends on why you want a different shape. you might as well use `tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D`

Comment: @NicolasGervais, as stated in the question, I want a different shape to apply an (arbitrary) existing model to it. I don't see how pooling helps with this, unless max/avg was all that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is an easy solution - using tensorflow [tf.space_to_batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/space_to_batch) and [tf.batch_to_space](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/batch_to_space) instead of Reshape does the trick:

```
        l1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((10, 3), name='inputs')
        l2 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.space_to_batch(x, [2, 1], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]))(l1)
        l3 = original_model(l2)
        l4 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.batch_to_space(x, [2, 1], [[0, 0], [0, 0]]))(l3)
```